# Google Cloud Run same URL on different containers

Tags: google-cloud-run

I have two containers (backend and frontend) that I want to access on the same URL. Looking at the Cloud Run documentation, I can't see how I can configure the following two containers.

- frontend => `example.com/`
- backend  => `example.com/api`

Is this possible?

Comment: This is a highly requested feature, stay tuned.

Comment: Agree with @Pentium10. Not directly possible for now, but things are in the pipe!

Comment: So it's possible on Google infrastructure, but you need to use Firebase hosting and URL re-writes pointed at the cloud run container.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation for Cloud Run [link](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains#base_path_mapping_not_supported):

> Base path mapping: not supported
>
> The term base path refers to the URL
> path name that is after the domain name. For example, users is the
> base path of **example.com/users**. Cloud Run only allows you to map a
> domain to /, not to a specific base path. So any path routing has to
> be handled by using a router inside the service's container or by
> using Firebase Hosting.